# Average degree of vertex at least distance r from boundary of a random geometric graph?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, geometric-graph

Given a random geometric graph $G(n, r)$, how can you estimate the average degree of a vertex that is at least distance $r$ from the boundary?

Note: I'm not asking for a simple expression, rather, how to think about and solve such a problem a step at a time.

Comment: What percentage of the area is points which connects to your point

Comment: Also posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/47625/755

Comment: @D.W. I deleted the post on CS.SE per your comment and have asked it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem can be solved using the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity). The average degree can be not only estimated but given exactly.

I interpret your notation to mean that $n$ vertices are independently uniformly distributed in the unit square and two vertices are joined by an edge if their distance is $\le r$. Then a given vertex $v$ at least distance $r$ from the boundary shares an edge with another vertex if that vertex lies in a circle of radius $r$ around $v$. The probability for this is $\pi r^2$. Thus by linearity of expectation the expected number of vertices that share an edge with $v$ is $(n-1)\pi r^2$.

Comment: Yes, the assumptions you made are correct ($n$ vertices, edges where distances are $\le r$. I'll spend time with the linearity of expectation. The fact that it is $n\pi r^2$ confuses me!

Comment: @ybakos: Sorry, I forgot to subtract the vertex itself, which doesn't have an edge with itself, so it's $(n-1)\pi r^2$.

Comment: @ybakos: And no thanks for potentially wasting my time by cross-posting without even providing a link to the other post. Very bad style.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. D.W. had linked to this post in the comment, and I took his recommendation to ask the question here. I deleted the question over at CS.SE - but you saw it before I had a chance to delete.