# Average node degree k in a geometric random graph is $\frac{\Pi r^2n}{l^2}$

Tags: proof-writing, random-graphs, geometric-probability

The paper "Small-Worlds: Strong Clustering in Wireless Networks" (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1063.pdf) is indicating empirically that the average node degree $<k>$ is (or can be approximated by) $\frac{\Pi r^2n}{l^2}$ whereby two nodes are connected if they are within range $r$, $n$ is number of nodes, $l$ length of the square.

I am trying to prove this relationship but I couldn't get anywhere. Any idea how to prove or disprove it? Some simulations I did should that it gets close to average node degree k if the length $l$ is considerably larger than $r$. This makes sense, since the border influence is diminished for these cases. At the border a node does have a limited number of neighbors only.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Orx.jpg)[See figure as example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid border influences, you can consider the geometric random graph (GRR) on a torus (which amounts in changing slightly the distance function).

In a GRR, the average degree is the number of vertices at distance less than $r$, i.e. the number of vertices that fall  within a circle of radius $r$. Then consider that there are $n-1$ vertices that, uniformly distributed, have a probability $\pi r^2 / l^2$ (area of the circle over the total area) to be neighbors.

Comment: Very interesting. As I mentioned I am keen to find the proof. Do you have any info which could help me?

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't satisfy you. Everything follows from the definition. What would you want explained?

Comment: I would appreciate any more detail clarification.I understand that we are calculating the node degree only for the considered node and not the average node degree of all nodes. That is maybe why the $n$ is missing in your term. I assume it makes a difference to consider the $n$ case to be different than the $1$ case, because the probabilities are changing and one additional node on the torus can add multiple additional links depending on location and proximity to existing nodes. If you could elaborate on your approach in more detail, it would be helpful for me.

Comment: @Derb  The reasoning gives you the expected degree of a vertex without any hypothesis, so it gives you the average degree. The $n$ is not missing, there's a $n-1$ factor in the expression. You can also check this similar answer to the same question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454271/average-degree-of-vertex-at-least-distance-r-from-boundary-of-a-random-geometric

Comment: Yes, I see now more clearly where it is going. Let's question: how does the torus assumption influence the reasoning and result? You mentioned a different distance function (what happens to $l$)?

Comment: The torus does not change anything, you still have a square of size $l$, but you take $\sqrt(\min(|x_1 - x_2|, l - |x_1 - x_2|)^2 + \min(|y_1 - y_2|, l - |y_1-y_2|)^2)$ instead of the euclidian distance.
This is just to avoid the border effects: vertices that are close to the border (or worse, the corner) will have on average less neighbors (because the available area around them is smaller). So to show that this result is accurate on a square you need to evaluate the border effect. If it vanishes as $n$ goes to infinity, the the initial formula is asymptotically correct.